# How to get training accuracy for a model after completing the training process?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is there a way to calculate the training accuracy after completing training process with Keras or Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

`model.history` has all the information required.

For example, after running model for 5 epochs, you can access the loss and accuracy as follows

```
history=model.history.history
print(history)
{'loss': [0.2212433920122683, 0.097910506768773, 0.06874677832927555, 0.05441241036520029, 0.0430859369851804], 'accuracy': [0.9342333, 0.9698667, 0.97786665, 0.98211664, 0.9856]}
```

If you want to access `loss` and `accuracy` during `model.evaluate`, you can do as follows

```
history2 =model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(history2) # output[0.07691180044879548, 0.9772]
```

Comment: Can I use model.evaluate(trainX, trainY) to measure training loss and accuracy?

Comment: You cannot use `model.evaluate` to measure loss and accuracy during training. If you want to measure `loss` and 'accuracy` during training, then you need to run `model.fit` and collect the parameters in `history`.  If my response answers your question then select it as "Answer". See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: What I want is to get the final loss and accuracy of the model and if model.evaluate() can give me the result or not. By the way I tested it and it worked. Thanks for your help and cooperation.